# In Autofac, what is the difference between RegisterAssemblyOpenGenericTypes and RegisterAssemblyTypes with AsClosedTypesOf?

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a generic interface that is implemented by a more than one concrete class. For example:

```cs
public interface IMyInterface<T> {}
internal class Impl1 : IMyInterface<int> {}
internal class Impl2 : IMyInterface<float> {}
```

I want to automatically register all implementations of `IMyInterface<T>` so that I can resolve a specific implementation supported for type `T` (in this case, either `int` or `float`). For example:

```cs
class TheConsumer
{
  // `impl` should resolve to `Impl1`
  public TheConsumer(IMyInterface<int> impl) {}
}
```

From what I can gather from [this github issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/215) and [the documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html?highlight=registergeneric#open-generic-components), there seems to be two mechanisms to do this:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Mechanism 1
builder.RegisterAssemblyOpenGenericTypes(typeof(Startup).Assembly)
    .AssignableTo(typeof(IMyInterface<>))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();

// Mechanism 2
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Startup).Assembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IMyInterface<>))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

I've only managed to test the 2nd mechanism shown above. The first one I am *speculating* is the same; but it may not be. Overall I'm just really confused about how "generics" are handled in Autofac. The docs are also missing any mention of `RegisterAssemblyOpenGenericTypes`, which doesn't help. So here are my questions:

- What is the functional difference between the two versions above?
- In what case would you choose one or the other?
- What is an "open" and "closed" generic (terminology from the Autofac documentation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is an "open" and "closed" generic (terminology from the Autofac documentation)?

An open generic has an undefined type argument (e.g. `List<T>`). Whereas, a closed generic has a defined type argument (e.g. `List<int>`).

> - What is the functional difference between the two versions above?

Currently, both of your implementations are "closed" generic implementations of `IMyInterface<T>`:

```
internal class Impl1 : IMyInterface<int> { }
internal class Impl2 : IMyInterface<float> { }
```

When you use `RegisterAssemblyOpenGenericTypes` ("Mechanism 1") with these, you get an exception that `IMyInterface<int>` is unknown when resolving `TheConsumer`. When you use `RegisterAssemblyTypes` with these closed generic implementations, `Impl1` is passed as expected when resolving `TheConsumer`.

The usage of `RegisterAssemblyOpenGenericTypes` can then be illustrated by extending your example a bit. If you add another implementation of `IMyInterface<T>` such as:

```
internal class Impl3<T> : IMyInterface<T> { }
```

You know have an "open" generic implementation of `IMyInterface<T>`. So when you go back to `RegisterAssemblyOpenGenericTypes` ("Mechanism 1") and try to resolve `TheConsumer`, it works and `Impl3<int>` is passed in.

> In what case would you choose one or the other?

Using `RegisterAssemblyTypes` with the "closed" generic types as you currently have, users of `IMyInterface<T>` will only be able to resolve the interface if it's specifically implemented with that type (e.g. `IMyInterface<int>` is implemented by `Impl1`). This can be ideal when you only want a certain set of type arguments that you want used in `IMyInterface<T>`.

Using `RegisterAssemblyOpenGenericTypes` can be useful when you don't actually care what the type arguments used in `IMyInterface<T>` are. This essentially just allows more flexible usage of `IMyInterface<T>`, which is something you may or may not want.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is great and it really made sense. It's a real shame this exact answer isn't in the Autofac docs; I think it would help bring a bunch of complex related aspects of this together in a nice way!